# Splitting HTML into multiple columns with Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Note: This is an alternate planned approach to this question: [Multiple column articles in Joomla](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238138/multiple-column-articles-in-joomla)

I've got a client who wants a multi column layout, which should be generated automatically from a non-column HTML block.

What is the feasibility of using JavaScript (and jQuery) to create a multi-column system from a single block of HTML?  And if it is possible how would I go about doing it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just an example how you can solve your problem. Of cause this solution can be refined.

```
function textSplitter(){
}

textSplitter.prototype.LENGTH_TO_SPLIT=5000 //max chars in single line

textSplitter.prototype.split=function(id){
    var contentDiv=document.getElementById(id); // get an element
    var text=contentDiv.innerHTML; 
    var length= text.length; 
    if(length){
        var div1sbstr=text.substring(0,this.LENGTH_TO_SPLIT); //take a substring
        var div1=document.createElement("div");
        contentDiv.appendChild(div1); // append it
    }
    if(length>this.LENGTH_TO_SPLIT){
        var div2sbstr=text.substring(this.LENGTH_TO_SPLIT,this.LENGTH_TO_SPLIT*2);
        var div2=document.createElement("div");
        contentDiv.appendChild(div2);
    }
    if(length>this.LENGTH_TO_SPLIT*2){
        var div3sbstr=text.substring(this.LENGTH_TO_SPLIT*2,this.LENGTH_TO_SPLIT*3);
        var div3=document.createElement("div");
        contentDiv.appendChild(div3);
    }
}
```

Comment: As the goal is some approxiamately equal height columns (I suppose), wouldn't it be more intelligent to calcute the heights of the containing <p> or <div> elements? Is this possible?

Comment: Yes it is possible i suppose. Of cause you can refine solution - this is just a hitn on how to start.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an unordered list with negative margins.

```
<ul>
   <li class="col1">Eggs</li>
   <li class="col1">Ham<li>
   <li class="col2 top">Bread<li>
   <li class="col2">Butter<li>
   <li class="col3 top">Flour<li>
   <li class="col3">Cream</li>
</ul>

ul {list-style:none;}
li {line-height:1.3em;}
.col2 {margin-left:100px;}
.col3 {margin-left:200px;}
.top {margin-top:-2.6em;} /* the clincher */
```

All code taken from [Smashing Magazine - The Definitive Guide to Using Negative Margins](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/07/27/the-definitive-guide-to-using-negative-margins/).