# Split div's content in two columns with Javascript

Tags: javascript, multiple-columns

I'm trying to find a way to split the content of one div and split it into two columns by following a logic process.

With a logic process, I mean that I'd like to split the content more or less in a half but without breaking the last sentence of the first column for example.

So I'd like to let finish the last sentence of the first column and than split the other part and print it in the other column, this is why it is almost never "cut in half".

So I'd like to keep my first column in this way:

Lorem ipsum dolor sit 
amet, consectetur 
adipiscing elit. 
Curabitur luctus orci 
in metus venenatis 
luctus orci in metus 
venenatis mattis

instead of something similar that might happens by cutting it in a half:

First column:
Lorem ipsum dolor sit 
amet, consectetur 
adipiscing elit. 
Curabitur luctus orci 
in metus venenatis 
luctus orci in metus 
venenatis

Second column:
mattis ... etc (rest second col)

It is really difficult to find documentation regarding this, I've been searching for a while.

I was try to follow this:

[Splitting HTML into multiple columns with Javascript/jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238155/splitting-html-into-multiple-columns-with-javascript-jquery)

But it doesn't seem to split anything at the moment:

HTML

```
<div id="split">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent molestie felis eu nisl gravida, sed molestie tortor egestas. Integer a velit quis mauris vehicula sagittis nec in dui. Suspendisse potenti. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Donec convallis pharetra diam, id rutrum purus porta eu. Morbi feugiat mauris sed viverra volutpat. Pellentesque aliquam, nibh ac accumsan vehicula, ex justo blandit quam, at rhoncus turpis neque id est.
</div>
```

JS

```
function textSplitter(){
}

textSplitter.prototype.LENGTH_TO_SPLIT=5000 //max chars in single line

textSplitter.prototype.split=function(){
    var contentDiv=document.getElementById("split"); // get an element
    var text=contentDiv.innerHTML; 
    var length= text.length; 
    if(length){
        var div1sbstr=text.substring(0,this.LENGTH_TO_SPLIT); //take a substring
        var div1=document.createElement("div");
        contentDiv.appendChild(div1); // append it
    }
    if(length>this.LENGTH_TO_SPLIT){
        var div2sbstr=text.substring(this.LENGTH_TO_SPLIT,this.LENGTH_TO_SPLIT*2);
        var div2=document.createElement("div");
        contentDiv.appendChild(div2);
    }
    if(length>this.LENGTH_TO_SPLIT*2){
        var div3sbstr=text.substring(this.LENGTH_TO_SPLIT*2,this.LENGTH_TO_SPLIT*3);
        var div3=document.createElement("div");
        contentDiv.appendChild(div3);
    }
}
```

Any precious idea?

Comment: Whether you want to split it into two or multiple column?

Comment: The result will have to be of two columns but at this stage also three is fine because I'd just like to understand the process than I can edit it to get two columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code receive a text as variable, split it into small pieces as you want and set in variables. Then show them in 2 columns side by side.

```js
var text = `I'm trying to find a way to split the content of one div and split it into two columns by following a logic process. With a logic process, I mean that I'd like to split the content more or less in a half but without breaking the last sentence of the first column for example. o I'd like to let finish the last sentence of the first column and than split the other part and print it in the other column, this is why it is almost never "cut in half". Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur luctus orci in metus venenatis luctus orci in metus venenatis`,
  numberOfLineChars = 30;

var output = [];

for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
  var startPos = i;
  var spcePos = 0;
  for (var j = 0; j < numberOfLineChars; j++) {
    if (text[i] == " ") {
      spcePos = i;
    }
    i++;
    if (i >= text.length) break;
  }
  if (i < text.length) {
    i = spcePos - 1;
    output.push(text.substr(startPos, spcePos - startPos + 1) + "\n");
  } else {
    output.push(text.substr(startPos, text.length - startPos + 1) + "\n");
  }
}

var num1 = Math.floor(output.length / 2),
  firstColumn = "<div class='one'>",
  secondColumn = "<div class='two'>";
for (var i = 0; i < num1; i++) {
  firstColumn += `<p>${output[i]}</p>`;
}
firstColumn += "</div>";
for (var i = num1; i < output.length; i++) {
  secondColumn += `<p>${output[i]}</p>`;
}
secondColumn += "</div>"
$('#content').append(firstColumn).append(secondColumn);
```

```css
p {
  text-align: justify;
}

.content {
  background: aqua;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 10px;
}

.one {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 40%;
  background: red;
  float: left;
}

.two {
  width: 40%;
  float: right;
  padding: 10px;
  background: black;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="content">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not limited to JS you could use CSS [columns](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/columns/).

Comment: I'm limited to JS because I will get the content through JS variable so I need to split the content of that variable in the right way and then print it in two columns.

Answer (score 0):

there are some (logic)bugs in your code but this should get you on the right track

- missing semicolon after `split=function() {...};
- textSplitter.prototype.LENGTH_TO_SPLIT=5000 and only using a text with 443 characters ;)
- ...

```js
window.onload = function() {

function TextSplitter(){ }

TextSplitter.prototype.LENGTH_TO_SPLIT=200; // changed this to 200

TextSplitter.prototype.split=function(){
    var contentDiv=document.getElementById("split"); 
    var text=contentDiv.innerHTML; 
    var length = text.length;
    var sentences = text.split('.');  // split the paragraph into sentences

    // for simplicity I just gonna generate two divs
    if(length>this.LENGTH_TO_SPLIT){
        var div1sbstr = '';
        do {
            div1sbstr += sentences.shift() + '.'; // because of split() we need to add a dot
        } while(div1sbstr.length < this.LENGTH_TO_SPLIT) 

        var div2sbstr = sentences.join('.');
        
        var div1 = document.createElement("div");
        var div2 = document.createElement("div");
        
        div1.innerHTML = div1sbstr;
        div2.innerHTML = div2sbstr;

        // not making them child of <div id="split"> but of <body>
        document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(div1); 
        document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(div2);
    }
    };

var texsplit = new TextSplitter()
texsplit.split()

}
```

```css
div {
padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="split">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent molestie felis eu nisl gravida, sed molestie tortor egestas. Integer a velit quis mauris vehicula sagittis nec in dui. Suspendisse potenti. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Donec convallis pharetra diam, id rutrum purus porta eu. Morbi feugiat mauris sed viverra volutpat. Pellentesque aliquam, nibh ac accumsan vehicula, ex justo blandit quam, at rhoncus turpis neque id est.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To split into 2 column, try this,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var textStr = $('#split')[0].innerText;
        var length = textStr.length;
        var halfLength = parseInt(length / 2);
        var div1 = document.createElement("div");
        var div1Str = textStr.substring(0, halfLength);
        if (textStr.substring((halfLength) + 1, 1) != ".")
            div1Str=div1Str.concat(textStr.substring((halfLength) + 1, textStr.indexOf(".", (halfLength) + 1) + 1));
        textStr=textStr.replace(div1Str,'');
        $('body').append("<div>" + div1Str + "</div>");
        if (textStr != "") {
            $('body').append("<div>" + textStr.substring(textStr.indexOf(".", (halfLength) + 1) + 2, length) + "</div>");
        }
    });
```